# Redirect to another page outside iframe wrapper

Tags: joomla-2.5, menu, redirect, wrapper

I'm using iframe wrapper menu to add my own custom code.
Inside the custom code, there is this button when click will generate a link to open another page.
I'd rather have it as clicking the button and immediately go to that another page. I did so but that another page will show inside the iframe wrapper content instead of opening new window.
Any idea how to redirect that another page to a new window after click button in iframe wrapper page?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can edit the contents of the iframe wrapper, you can use the `target` attribute. There are several options depending on what you want to do:

- `<a target="_parent" href="yourlink.html">Text</a>`
  Will open the link in the parent frame
- `<a target="_blank" href="yourlink.html">Text</a>`
  This will open the link in a new browser window
- `<a target="_full" href="yourlink.html">Text</a>`
  This will open the link in the full browser window
- `<a target="framename" href="yourlink.html">Text</a>`
  This will open the link in the frame named **framename**. It will be created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried <a> tag attribute and it works fine of course, but rather than create a link using a tag to open that another page, I'd rather use the button to directly open that another page than generate a link (<a> tag)... But whenever I clicked the button to go directly to that another page, it showed the page within the iframe wrapper instead of new window.

Comment: What code are you using to display the button? Can't you simply style your tag like a button using CSS?

Comment: I'm using <input type="submit" value="Go">, when user click that, that page itself will do processing to check whether she/he has the access rights before going to another page...

Comment: Have you tried adding the `target` attribute to your `<form>`, e.g. `<form target="_parent" action=...`? However, it would probably be better to avoid using an iframe if possible. There are many ways to include custom code in your articles and modules, with extensions like [Sourcerer](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) or [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-html-advanced).

Comment: omg! it works!! thanks for your help! why it would be good to avoid using iframe?? I think that's the easiest way to add custom code in joomla menu instead of using another extension or plugin...